# Why isn't this reading from the specified file?

Tags: java, p2p

I'm working on a simple, model peer-to-peer networking system. The bootstrap server is supposed to serve a text file containing lists of IPs that connected to nodes to help each node discover more peers. However, it doesn't write the file like it should, and I don't understand why. Here's what I have so far:

```
package network;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PeerBootstrapServer 
{ 
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String peerFilePath = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please provide a peer list path:");

    File file = new File(peerFilePath);

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(8088);
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Socket socket = listener.accept();                              
            try
            {
                String peer = socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();

                boolean isRecognized = false;

                for(String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; )
                {
                    if(line == peer)
                    {
                        isRecognized = true;
                    }
                }

                if(isRecognized == false)
                {
                    writer.newLine();
                    writer.write(peer);
                }

                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                for(String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; )
                {
                    out.println(line);
                }                   
            }
            finally
            {
                socket.close();
            }
        }
    }

    finally
    {
        listener.close();
        reader.close();
        writer.close();
    }
  }
}
```

any help and/or tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are opening a `BufferedWriter` and a `BufferedReader` on the same file. That can't be right?

Comment: It needs to open it to read the list of IP's to check if there's already one listed before it adds (aka writes) it as a new one. It's right, it just might not be correct :)

Comment: Ok, good. Didn't really read the rest of the code thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that after the first loop reading the input stream, you reach the end of it, then when you do the second loop, `reader.readLine()` just return `null`.

You have to call `reset()` before the second loop. e.g.

```
reader.reset();
for(String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; )
{
    out.println(line);
}
```

EDIT
In your case, it may be better to open the reader and writer for each connexion and not once and for all. The same idea if you need to read first for a lookup then to send the content.

Comment: Then I get... Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: H:\peers.txt
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at network.PeerNode.main(PeerNode.java:11)

Comment: Well, for a start, it does not look like a good idea to try to read and write in the same file at the same time, and you have to manage concurrency access by 2 peers. So my answer is certainly not enough...